# How do I get the Python line number and file name of the point this function was called from?

Tags: python

I have the following python code shown with line numbers is a file called "myFile.py".

```
 1:   import traceback
 2:   import sys
 3:   
 4:   def a():
 5:       print "-" * 80
 6:       print "A: %s" % "SOMETHING_1"
 7:       print "-" * 80
 8:   
 9:   
10:   def b():
11:       print "*" * 80
12:       print "B: %s" % SOMETHING_2
13:       a()
14:       print "*" * 80
15:   
16:   
17:   b()
```

Currently it simply prints:

```
B: SOMETHING_2
A: SOMETHING_1
```

However, I would like to change it such that SOMETHING_1 and SOMETHING_2 are replaced by the filename and line number from which their function was called. So I would like it to produce the following output:

```
B: myFile.py:17
A: myFile.py:12
```

How can I do that? What do I need to replace SOMETHING_1 and SOMETHING_2 to make it work?
I have experimented a bit with the traceback and sys modules but haven't yet landed on a suitable solution.